# QuickTime does not see EpocCam after updating to Big Sur

Tags: video, permission, quicktime, webcam, big-sur

After updating to macOS Big Sur my webcam iOS app (EpocCam Pro) no longer connects to QuickTime and other recording software on Mac.

The iOS app was able to connect to the EpocCam service via USB, but EpocCam is no longer listed as a video source in QuickTime.

Before the OS update, I was able to establish the connection. Other users seem to have the same problem, but the developer of the app claims that it is working.

Can this be further investigated?

Specs:

- Mac OS: Big Sur 11.0.1 (20B29)
- EpocCam driver: 2.3
- EpocCam app:
  2020.5

[image: EpocCam service]
[image: EpocCam files and ports]

Comment: Did you reinstall EpocCam?

Comment: Yes, reinstalled the iOS app. Also the driver, but without removing any old files.

Comment: I just reinstalled the driver on Big Sur, works as expected in Zoom and OBS. It doesn't work in QuickTime but then I never checked whether it did before.

Comment: Did you specifically ask the Developers about QuickTime?

Comment: OTOH it does work with QuickTime and https://reincubate.com/camo/ so this looks like an EpocCam issue after all

Comment: I did not raise a support request, the information is from their website https://help.elgato.com/hc/en-us/articles/360052071492-macOS-Big-Sur-compatibility

Comment: Ah. Well, it does work with Zoom for me. Did you only test QuickTime or other applications as well? If it doesn't work at all it might help to reach out to Epoc on this.

Comment: Camo looks good (the desktop app) I am considering sticking with it for a while. Will contact Epoc for support in the meantime.

Comment: Also tried with Skype, there it doesn't work as well..

Comment: Camo has the same problem with QuickTime, they are working on it with Apple. Up to date information is available in "Help & Integrations" in the desktop app. I was able to fix Skype using a patch found there, it also made EpocCam work.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Camo works with QT for me.

Answer (score 1):

In Big Sur certain applications (including QuickTime Player) block virtual webcams like EpocCam.
See here: [EpocCam help page](https://help.elgato.com/hc/en-us/articles/360052178932-EpocCam-Supported-and-unsupported-applications-on-macOS)